# "Missing class name" error on doctrine:build-schema

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I have a project that connects to multiple databases. When I run doctrine:build-schema, I get an error that simply says "Missing class name."

Any idea what could be going on? I suspect it has something to do with the fact that I'm connecting to multiple databases since this is the only project where I'm having this problem and this is the only project where I connect to multiple databases.

Edit: I have two databases: `galapagos` and `survey`. It looks like the problem has something to do with the fact that `survey` has some foreign keys that reference tables in `galapagos`. When I take away these foreign keys, `build-schema` works fine.

Comment: I have an idea - maybe the class name is missing? :)

Comment: Well yeah, but missing from where?

Comment: There is no schema. I'm trying to build it via `build-schema`.

Answer (score 0):

i'm no expert on Doctrine but maybe what's been happening is that galapagos relates to a class (table a mean) from survey, but galapagos is being parsed first, so when it reaches  a line with something like:

```
foreignClass: Zaraza
```

It does not understand what your talking about willies :P. So , try defining both databases on a single file, or try to alter the orden in witch files are being loaded. That might help!

Answer (score -1):

First, you should create the model with the following command:

```
php symfony doctrine:build-model
```

Then, construct the schema executing the following command:

```
php symfony doctrine:build-schema
```